# push html content with slide out menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

hey I'm trying to make a slide out menu push the html content when the menu icon is clicked on. the site page is..[sitepage](http://blog.dundaah.com/docs/mon)
the div menu is..

```html
<div class="slideout-menu">
 <h3>Last Week<a href="#" class="slideout-menu-toggle">&times;</a></h3>
 <ul>
  <li><center><img border="0px"draggable="false" align="middle" src="img/fbump.png" alt="dundaah_logo" width="220" height="220"></center></li>
  <li><a href="http://dundaah.com/docs/mon.html">Dundaah</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://pics.dundaah.com/docs/mon.html">Pics</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://vidz.dundaah.com/docs/mon.html">Videos</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://music.dundaah.com/docs/mon.html">Music</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

its activated by the following js code..

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.slideout-menu-toggle').on('click', function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     // create menu variables
     var slideoutMenu = $('.slideout-menu');
     var slideoutMenuWidth = $('.slideout-menu').width();
     
     // toggle open class
     slideoutMenu.toggleClass("open");
     
     // slide menu
     if (slideoutMenu.hasClass("open")) {
      slideoutMenu.animate({
       left: "0px"
      }); 
     } else {
      slideoutMenu.animate({
       left: -slideoutMenuWidth
      }, 250); 
     }
    });
});
```

i read that i can do this with css but i've tried and its not working...

```css
.slideout-menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: -250px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #333;
  z-index: 100;
  
 }
 .slideout-menu h3 {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 400;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #222;
 }
 .slideout-menu .slideout-menu-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 9px 5px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
  background: #222;
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: top;
 }
 .slideout-menu .slideout-menu-toggle:hover {
  color: #fff;
 }
 .slideout-menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  font-weight: 300;
  border-top: 1px solid #151515;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #454545;
 }
 .slideout-menu ul li {
  border-top: 1px solid #454545;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #151515;
 }
 .slideout-menu ul li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
 }
 .slideout-menu ul li a:hover {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
 }
 .slideout-menu ul li a i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 10px;
  opacity: .5;
 }
```

what i'm i doing wrong? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.slideout-menu-toggle').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        // create menu variables
        var slideoutMenu = $('.slideout-menu');
        var slideoutMenuWidth = $('.slideout-menu').width();

        // toggle open class
        slideoutMenu.toggleClass("open");

        // slide menu
        if (slideoutMenu.hasClass("open")) {
            slideoutMenu.animate({
                left: "0px"
            }); 
        } else {
            slideoutMenu.animate({
                left: -slideoutMenuWidth
            }, 250);    
        }

        if (slideoutMenu.hasClass("open")) {
            $('body').animate({
                'margin-left': slideoutMenuWidth
            }); 
        } else {
            $('body').animate({
                'margin-left': "0px"
            }, 250);    
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: unfortunately when i decrease the browser width, the slide out menu appears on the right side without being clicked

Comment: no worries, it was something else, thanks for your code.

Answer (score 0):

i think what's wrong is that "left:-250" you need to add the "px"

```
.slideout-menu {
    position:fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: -250px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #333;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

check this
http://jsfiddle.net/pbqb964k/2/